# Object with default argument constructor can be declared inside another class with not yet declared variable as constructor parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, default-arguments

I tried to google my question, but given the title I find it hard to formulate properly, so I wasn't able to find anything. So I decided to ask here: why does this compile?

```
#include <cstdio>

class Test
{
  public:
    Test(int param = 42)
    {
      printf("ctor %d\n", param);
      _data = param;
    }
    
  private:
    int _data = 0;
};

class Test2
{
  // wtf? v is not yet declared
  Test t{ v };
  int v = 333;
};

int main()
{
  Test2 t2;

  // This doesn't compile though.  
  // Test t{ v };
  // int v = 333;

  printf("don't optimize 0x%X\n", &t2);
  
  return 0;
}
```

I expected the compiler to issue an error of "undeclared variable v" or something.

Also, Test constructor always prints 0 even if I declare v const.

Of course, if I rearrange lines like this:

```
int v = 333;
Test t{ v };
```

then it works as expected.

Comment: `v` *is* declared. It's a member of `Test2` ; `int v = 333;`.

Comment: _"...The potential scope of a name declared in a class begins at the point of declaration and includes the rest of the class body, all the derived classes bodies, the function bodies (even if defined outside the class definition __or before the declaration of the name__),"_ .  See [Class scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Class_scope)

Comment: But the value is not assigned, even if I declare v const. Constructor still prints 0. Does it have something to do with implicit call to move constructor or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed to by [@RichardCritten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten) in comment, [class scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Class_scope) says (emphasis are mine):

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class begins at the point of declaration and includes the rest of the class body, all the derived classes bodies, the function bodies (even if defined outside the class definition **or before the declaration of the name)**, function default arguments, function exception specifications, **in-class brace-or-equal initializers**, and all these things in nested classes, recursively.

In your case, it's a "in-class brace-or-equal initializers":

```cpp
class Test2
{
  // wtf? v is not yet declared
  Test t{ v };   // <= This is a in-class brace-or-equal initializers
  int v = 333;
};
```

A compiler probably has to do two passes in order to process this information.

---

> Also, Test constructor always prints 0 even if I declare v const.

As for why you are getting zero printed, this is due the order of initialization. All members are initialized in order of declaration - this is the golden rule (no matter whether you are using initializers in the class definition or in a constructor). In your case, `t` is initialized before `v`.

This makes your code contain undefined behavior, since you try to use the value of `v` before it is initialized.

> ... even if I declare v const

`const` doesn't change anything in this case. A const non-static member is still a non-static member. You have to make it `constexpr static` or `static const` to make a difference.